# Null file when uploading via MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following form on an .NET MVC View:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Video/UploadDocument"> 
<input type="file" id="document1" name="document1"/> 
<input type="submit"  value="Save"/> 
</form>
```

And the controller has the following signature that gets called:

```
public ActionResult UploadDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
    return View();
}
```

When I break inside the UploadDocument method, the parameter 'file' is null.  I've selected a valid document on my desktop and know it contains text.  What am I missing to get this file upload working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["document1"];
```

There's probably something wrong with bindings (`[Bind()]` attribute).

Edit: And make that method `public ActionResult UploadDocument() {}`.

Comment: Tried that and it worked....totally don't get why that fixes it.  Wierd.  Thanks though!

Comment: I only have 1 idea why it began to work: If I remeber, after modifying controller code, the application had to be compiled again for changes to take effect. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered but I believe the culprit is your signature. Instead of "**file**", use "**document1**".

```
public ActionResult UploadDocument(HttpPostedFileBase document1) 
{ 
    return View(); 
}
```

Please try and let me know your result

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you make the name of the argument (file) and the name of the input element equal? I recall that the default model binding logic in ASP.NET MVC works using this convention.

Comment: Still null.  Changed 'file' to 'document1' and still had null.  :(